# What are some good microcontroller development boards to learn the .Net micro framework?

Tags: .net, embedded, .net-micro-framework

Excluding the Micro Framework Emulator ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A well known one is [Tahoe](http://devicesolutions.net/Products/Tahoe/tabid/55/Default.aspx). Others are

- http://www.sjjmicro.com/EDK.html
- http://www.ghielectronics.com/details.php?id=107&sid=108

Answer (score 1):

I recommend http://www.netduino.com It is Pin Compatible with the Arduino so all kinds of hardware shields are available see http://www.sparkfun.com. The price is also very reasonable at $35 to $60 (The Plus model supports Ethernet and SD card with no change in Arduino Compatibility.

**Note:** the Netduino/Netduino Plus operate at 3.3V but are 5V tolerant and have 8mA of current available on each pin instead of the 20 mA on Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

**[Domino](http://www.tinyclr.com/hardware/1/fez-domino)** and **[Panda](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/135/)** with it's many Arduino compatible shields are highly affordable and well supported.